# Insert space between a list in Angular4 and transform to link each element

Tags: html, angular

I have an object with 'id' and 'name', and I want to get something like this on the html

> Category1, Category2, Category3

I am trying with this:

```
<span *ngFor="let category of categories; let isLast = last" class="categories">
   {{category.name}}{{isLast ? '' : ', '}}
</span>
```

But I am getting this:

```
Category1,Category2,Category3
```

What I need to do to get spaces after the comma?

Comment: `', '` -> `',&nbsp;'`

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` after `,`

Comment: why dont you just concatenate the string objects instead of rendering multiple span elements?

Comment: Because I'd like to make each one an independent 'link' using the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the opposite what you're supposed to do. You should do this:

```
<span *ngFor="let category of categories; let isLast = last" class="categories"  >
    <span *ngIf="!isLast" [innerHTML]="category.name + ';&nbsp;'"></span>
     <span *ngIf="isLast" [innerHTML]="category.name"></span>
</span>
```

Or you can do this also:

```
    <span *ngFor="let category of categories; let isLast = last" class="categories"  >
        <ng-template *ngIf="!isLast else elseForLast">{{category.name}};&nbsp;</ng-template>
        <ng-template #elseForLast>{{category.name}}</ng-template>
   </span>
```

Comment: That worked for me and solved my following step, but the loop ngFor is geting values in reverse order, so I am getting this: 'Cat1Cat2, Cat3, ' and if I use (!isLast) I get 'Cat1, Cat2Cat3'

Answer (score 2):

You are doing exactly opposite check, check `!isLast` while adding `,`

```
{{!isLast ? ',&nbsp;' : ''}}
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rhzrIYrhJyUB1XOGzoRa?p=preview)

Comment: @Juanker did you check plunker.. It should work. having `single space` is fine AFAIK, if you tried to add multiple spaces, it would converted to `single space` while rendering HTML

Comment: Yes, I checked plunker but in my code it does not work :(